# How to override the function's output .ToString() in c#

Tags: c#, .net

I have a function which return type is `Object`, when function `return NULL`, I am getting a `object reference not set` error.
If I Use `.ToString()`. So how do I override the `.ToString()` to `return empty` when it `returns null`??

Comment: The thing to do here is to test for null before attempting to call ToString()

Comment: Overriding will not help, as Null is not an object type to call the overridden method

Comment: You could `override` your `.ToString()` , use `.IsNullOrEmtpy()`to check or use _null propagation_ Just google any of these and let us know if u need further help.

Answer (score 2):

That's impossible, you can't call a method on a `null`-object, aka you can't call a method on something that isn't there.

The only thing you can do is check for `null`:

```
if(theObj == null)
    Console.WriteLine("empty");
```

Or alternatively:

```
var someName = theObj != null ? theObj.ToString() : "empty";
```

Comment: Or simply:  `var someName = (theObj ?? "empty").ToString()`

Comment: Yep, indeed, lots of possibilities to check for null

Answer (score 1):

Before convert that object to string using `ToString()`, please check the object is null.